# Storing a instance/object in a array

Tags: c#, arrays, object, instance-variables

I am creating a console zombie survival game that is suppose be random and be fairly complex, such as finding multiple weapons, and ammo types. However, I believe that I could save an object in array to use it again later, for correct information, but this way does not work.

I have tried looking of storing objects in arrays with no luck. I have tried to change the arrays from Item based to Object based with no luck.

```
class Firearm : Weapon
    {
        public Firemode firemode;
        public int maxCapacity;
        public int curCapacity;
        public Type type;
        public Caliber caliber;

        public Firearm (string _name, float _damage, int _range, Firemode 
_firemode, int _maxCapacity, int _curCapacity, Type _type, Caliber 
_caliber)
        {
            name = _name;
            damage = _damage;
            range = _range;
            firemode = _firemode;
            maxCapacity = _maxCapacity;
            curCapacity = _curCapacity;
            type = _type;
            caliber = _caliber;
        }

        public void FirearmStats()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n Name: {0}\n Damage: {1}\n Range: {2}\n 
Firemode: {3}\n Max Capacity: {4}\n Current Capacity: {5}", name, damage, 
range, firemode, maxCapacity, curCapacity);
        }
    }


static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random numberGenerator = new Random();
        //Pistols
        Firearm m9 = new Firearm("Beretta M9A1", 34.0F, 30, 
Firemode.SemiAutomatic, 15, numberGenerator.Next(1, 16), Type.Pistol, 
Caliber.nine);
        ....
        Item[] inventory = new Item[14];
        Item[] equipped = new Item[0];
        .....
        equipped[0] = m9;
        Console.WriteLine("\nYou find a {0}", equipped[0].name);

        //issue here with equipped[0]^^^
        equipped[0].FirearmStats();

        //and here ^^^^^
        player.Command();
    }
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS1061  'Program.Item' does not contain a definition for 'FirearmStats' and no accessible extension method 'FirearmStats' accepting a first argument of type 'Program.Item' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    ZombieConsoleGame   E:\Visual Studio Projects\ZombieConsoleGame\ZombieConsoleGame\Program.cs    158 N/A

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the `Weapon` class inherits from your `Item` class.

Because the array `equipped` is of type `Item`, you need to cast the *Item* to a *Weapon* before you can call any of the methods/functions on the Weapon class.

Alter this line (where you highlighted the problem) `equipped[0].FirearmStats();`

to be:

```
((Firearm)equipped[0]).FirearmStats();
```

This will cast the *Item* to be a *Firearm* and then allow you to use it as a Firearm.

Edit:

In addition, the line:

```
Item[] equipped = new Item[0];
```

Will create an Array variable with Zero elements within it, no space has been allocated to store the items you are equipped with. Change the zero in `[0]` to be a positive number like you already have in the previous line for *inventory* (`Item[] inventory = new Item[14];`)

Comment: Side note/nitpick: It is not _Weapon_ but `FireArm` which declares the `FirearmStats` method ;-)

Comment: I  thought this would work after seeing it, but it did not. Then I thought I should change it to the cast as Firearm  instead. This got rid of any errors till I ran it. In the console it says "Unhandled Exception: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at ZombieConsoleGame.Program.Main(String[] args) in E:\Visual Studio Projects\ZombieConsoleGame\ZombieConsoleGame\Program.cs:line 157". I also tried changing the array to be of Weapon or Firearm but got the same error message in the console when running it.

Comment: @SubaruDanyBoon, pay attention to what the IndexOutOfRangeException tells you. Don't just blind-guess the problem, read the problem description given to you by the exception...

Comment: I have no clue why its saying that, should it not be within range, because the index is within range of the array size.

Comment: @SubaruDanyBoon, what is the actual array size?

Comment: `Item[] equipped = new Item[0];` creates an array of zero length.

Comment: Item[] equipped = new Item[0]; it creates 0 length array

Comment: @elgonzo Thank you for the pointer/nitpick on the incorrect cast, rather silly of me actually.